# Get name from another table using an ID

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've got two tables, one is called `matches` and the other one is called `teams`. `matches` only list team IDs, but I want my query to include team names from `teams`. I tried different solutions already and I came up with this query, but it didn't work:

```sql
SELECT *  FROM `matches` WHERE `mWeek` = 1
INNER JOIN `teams`.`tName` ON `matches`.`tHome` = `teams`.`tId`
```

That query returned error #1064. I'm happy to provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query will be like these

```
SELECT
    `matches`.*, 
    `teams`.`tName`
FROM
    `matches`
INNER JOIN `teams` ON `matches`.`teamId` = `teams`.`tId`
WHERE
    `mWeek` = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Works as supposed :)